# hadoop usage for non-mapreduce tasks

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, scheduling

Can we use hadoop as a framework just to schedule different tasks without using MapReduce paradigm?

I want to schedule group of tasks using my scheduling algorithm. According to my algorithm, tasks are to be run on different machines, but the whole computation of the task  should happen on a single machine.

Can we do this on hadoop? please give suggestions

Comment: I'd suggest you to have a look a the `YARN` architecture. The main Hadoop site as well as Hortonworks' blog have detailed descriptions. Have a look at YARN's `ResourceManager` it can handle pluggable scheduling policies.